# Ffmpeg энкодит/декодит видео на процессоре или видеокарте?

Tags: ffmpeg

Уменьшаю размер видео при помощи ffmpeg, команда вроде:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i d:\1b.mkv -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 -r:v 30 d:\1s.mp4
```

И возник вопрос о том при помощи чего ffmpeg производит обработку - на процессоре? Или на видеокарте?

И если на видеокарте то как его перенаправить на более мощную (ноут с 2 видеокартами)?

Comment: Это зависит от выбранного кодека. libx265 производит обработку только на процессоре.

Comment: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro

Comment: Ага, значит оно работает на полную, спасибо за информацию.